# Get "Object" return type from Func<MyClass, object>

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression

Let's suppose I have defined Func as follows:

```
Func<MyClass, object> f = o => o.StringProperty;
```

or

```
Func<MyClass, object> f = o => o.Property.SomeMethod();
```

Is there way to get the **actual** return type without specifically calling it?

Comment: "Get" the return type how exactly? A hypothetical example?

Comment: @Jon I think inferring the return type based on the fact the compiler knows this (`string` in the first example, return of `SomeMethod` in the second), however this example would collapse at run-time as the variable `f` could be re-assigned. Hypothetically, if `f` could not be re-assigned you could statically determine the return type by parsing the `Func` definition. Sounds like a candidate for Roslyn ;-)

Comment: Depending on your usage, perhaps you can leverage the `Expression` API to check the return type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression (this isn't an exact implementation of what you're trying to do, just a related example)

Comment: What would the "actual" return type be if you have something like `Func<MyClass, object> f1 = o => o.StringProperty; Func<MyClass, object> f2 = o => f1(o);`? Or even `Func<MyClass, object> f = o => { throw new NotImplementedException(); };`? :)

Comment: @hvd it's a good question in the case of throwing exception

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov: Are you retrieving these `f` delegates at runtime and are specifically typed as `Func<MyClass, object>`? Or would a slight change of syntax be ok, something like: `MemberInspector<MyClass>.GetReturnType(o => o.StringProperty)`?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, yes I retrieving these delegates at runtime and they are typed as Func<MyClass, object>

Comment: Then I think you may be out of luck. Perhaps you can change your design such that these delegates are defined at compile-time, or wrapped as an object that also stores the return type information where/when the delegates are defined. EDIT: Do you have the ability to change how callers define these delegates? Could you force the API they use to be something like `MyClassDelegate f = MyClassDelegate.Create(o => o.StringProperty)` rather than the code you posted?

Comment: (cont.)  And work with this custom class rather than a `Func<MyClass, object>` directly? The custom class can have an `Invoke` method that can invoke the delegate as well.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, I don't completely get it. What did you mean when you say "delegates wrapped as an object"?

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov: I posted an answer with an example and usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the return type like this:

```
f.Method.ReturnType
```

But this will return you the type `object`. If you want to get `Method` or `String` or something that derives from `object`, you won't be able to have the information unless you call the method.

Actually you could, but this would mean that you'd have to dissassemble the method core and then analyze it to see what the method can return. But even then, there might be many different return types.

So the answer is: if you want to know that it returns an object, then yes you can, otherwise it's not worth the trouble, and it's better to find another way of doing what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are retrieving these `Func<MyClass, object>` delegates at runtime from other sources, the type information is essentially lost.

Instead, where these functions are defined, you can have the callers essentially encode that type information in a wrapped delegate <s>by taking advantage of the [LINQ Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx) API</s> (EDIT: Silly me, far more simpler at this point; we already have the generic compile time information):

```
public class MyClassDelegate
{
    private readonly Func<MyClass, object> Function;

    public Type ReturnType { get; private set; }

    private MyClassDelegate(Func<MyClass, object> function, Type returnType)
    {
        this.Function = function;
        this.ReturnType = returnType;
    }

    public object Invoke(MyClass context)
    {
        return Function(context);
    }

    public static MyClassDelegate Create<TReturnType>(Func<MyClass, TReturnType> function)
    {
        Func<MyClass, object> nonTypedFunction = o => function(o);
        return new MyClassDelegate(nonTypedFunction, typeof(TReturnType));
    }
}
```

(A derived generic `MyClassDelegate<TReturnType> : MyClassDelegate` class could be made as well to get around some of the sillyness in the `Create` method, or avoid value-type boxing, or to have the return type information available at compile time or even by reflecting on whatever `MyClassDelegate<TReturnType>` is.)

Callers defining the delegates instead of working directly with a `Func<MyClass, object>` would instead work with this class and define their delegates as:

```
MyClassDelegate f1 = MyClassDelegate.Create(o => o.StringProperty);
MyClassDelegate f2 = MyClassDelegate.Create(o => o.Property.SomeMethod());
```

Your API would require a `MyClassDelegate`, with which you can easily access their types:

```
Console.WriteLine(f1.ReturnType.FullName); //string
Console.WriteLine(f2.ReturnType.FullName); //whatever `SomeMethod()` is declared to return
```

Finally, you can invoke the delegates or even create `Func<MyClass, object>` delegates still:

```
f1.Invoke(myClassInstance);
Func<MyClass, object> f3 = f1.Invoke;
```

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov: I've edited my answer; the LINQ expression API is unnecessary at this point. The key takeaway is to have callers encode this information when the delegate is created and leverage a wrapped delegate to pass the information throughout your API.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. When we want to do such things properly we should use Expressions anyway, I get it.

Comment: The `Expression` usage really only helps if you want to avoid the generic inference. That is, you could have `Create(Expression<Func<MyClass, object>> function)` and still determine the type used. But you may as well take advantage of generic type inference I used in my update.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to find not compile-time solution, without generic types.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something close to this by using a generic method to make the compiler infer the type arguments:

```
static Func<T1, R> Infer<T1, R>(Func<T1, R> f) { return f; }
```

And then:

```
var func = Infer((string s) => s.Length);
```

This will encode the return type into the type of `func` at compilation time.

Of course for a more generally applicable solution you would need a bunch of overloads of `Infer` to cover `Action` and `Func` with one, two, three, etc arguments.

If you then want to get the return type at runtime, for any kind of `Func` it's as simple as `func.Method.ReturnType` as ppetrov has already pointed out.

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov: Of course, if you already have `Func<string, object> f = s => s.Length` and you do `Infer(f)` you will get back a `Func<string, object>` -- there is no way to recover type information that has been "lost".

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov: If you want to do more then you have to work with `Expression<Func<...>>` and reflection instead.